# Replicate d3.js Dynamic tree in Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, d3.js

I would like to replicate this D3js [Dynamic Tree example](http://bl.ocks.org/1061834) using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). I am not able to use this example in IE8 since it doesn't support SVG. I need to find a alternative to this problem.

I have already been trying this using [d34raphael](http://webmonarch.github.com/d34raphael/) but there is not much documentation for me to get something working except for only a couple of basic examples.

Any suggestions on how to convert this Dynamic tree into Raphael would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the graph to be dynamic? You could copy the svg output and put it through an SVG to Raphael converter

Comment: Here's the thing about D3 - it's specifically built to use whatever rendering library you want. D3 handles the math, that's it. So you could just go through the example and replace the SVG references with Raphael references.

Comment: @Duopixel I need it to be dynamic. By the way, What do you mean by svg Output.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Really, I am going to try that and post back the results.

Comment: @Duopixel I know now what you mean by svg Output. Whatever comes is generated in the svg tag in the DOM. But I need it to be dynamic. I tried to convert an static version into raphael but I didn't look well.

Answer (score 1):

You can build this visualization with [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/). [The example on the Protovis page](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/dendrogram.html) page isn't dynamic but there are some examples of dynamic trees [in the tests](https://github.com/mbostock/protovis/blob/master/tests/layout/tree-toggle.html).

Protovis has pretty good MSIE 7/8 support through a VML rendering add-on: [Protovis-MSIE](https://github.com/DataMarket/protovis-msie) (disclaimer: I am the author of this).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot rely on any external add-on. I cannot ask clients to install add-ons in order to see this graph.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear: This add on is for Protovis, not for IE. Your users would not have to do a thing. IE already has VML support and the add-on just makes Protovis use VML rather than SVG in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was looking into Protovis and realized that it is not supported anymore. Which would make it hard to find answer to questions and resolve critical problems. The other issue is that there is not documentation for your plug-in so I don't know how to us it.